# Using userform to edit excel cells

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using this guide to create a small UI, but I'm specifically looking for a way to edit the cells when I click a specific row (instead of adding info as shown in the guide). So if let's say name is filled out, I'd like the UI to pop up with that name inside the textbox, and then the user can edit that name and/or add other information in that **`userform`**.

I realize I'd need to edit the code, and I'm a beginner to VBA, but will this guide help me with my idea or is there a simpler way to doing this?

Guide: [http://hubpages.com](http://hubpages.com/hub/How-to-write-Visual-Basic-code-to-configure-a-User-Interface-created-using-a-UserForm-in-Excel-2007-and-Excel-2010)

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out?  QUesitons asking to recommend a favorite tool or off-site resource are specifically prohibited here. I'd argue that questions asking "will this outside resource solve my problem?" are likewise off-limits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I helped some one out in a similar question.  See [Microsoft excel: Simple gui in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24195659/microsoft-excel-simple-gui-in-vba/24196056#24196056) Follow the example that I outlined there.  If you want the User Form to display the current contents of the cell from which the user was activated from then you need to while in the Visual Basic Editor / Code view of the form at the very top you will notice that there are two drop downs that change based upon which subroutine that you are in for which object.  For example if you were editing the code for "CommandButton1", and the "Click" Method (i.e. Private Sub CommandButton1_Click" the drop down show up as "CommandButton1" and "Click" respectively.  So you will want to select "UserForm" from the first drop down and "Activate" from the second drop down such that you are editing the "Private Sub UserForm_Activate()" function.  Code it as follows:

`Me.TextBox1.Value = ActiveCell.Value`

Provided that you followed the example which I gave in the previous answer which I linked you to the form will activate and have the current value of the cell that you came from, and then after modifying the value in the text field and pressing ok the cell will be updated with the value that you specified in to the textbox of the userform.

Comment: ***edited*** Hi thanks for your help. My approach is a bit different than yours. I wanted the user to click the edit button and it'll open up the userform. The form will have textboxes and combo boxes where each box is referred to a specific cell. My problem is I don't want to create a new userform and link each cell to a textbox this way everytime: `Private Sub UserForm_Activate()` `Me.TextBox1.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B4").Value` `End Sub` Especially since there will be an edit button for every row. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Yes it is possible and that resource which you pointed out appears to dive in to how that is done so yes to answer your question more directly the resource certainly will help you learn how to do what your doing.